# What is the version compatibility of Spring boot 2.6.0 and Spring Cloud?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud

I have updated my spring boot version to 2.6.0 and my spring cloud version is still Brixton.Build-SNAPSHOT (1.1.2.RELEASE). Now my application is not getting started. Giving some version compatibility issue. So Is there any compatibility list that I can refer to upgrade my spring cloud version as well ?

Comment: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-release/wiki/Supported-Versions#supported-releases

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See https://spring.io/projects/spring-cloud

"Use Spring Cloud 2021.0.x aka Jubilee for Spring Boot 2.6.x, 2.7.x (Starting with 2021.0.3)"

Latest 2021.0.x version is 2021.0.5.

Additional information: Spring Boot 2.6 reached end of life on 24 Nov 2022, current supported Spring Boot versions (02/2023) are 2.7.x and 3.x. See here: https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support